# Collaborative editing and publishing software

Tags: looking-for-a-script, cms

Is there any CMS that focuses on collaborative editing wiki-style by anyone and publishing? Wikis are usable, but there is no 'publishing' per se - when you save a page and want others to work on it, it will be available to view to all. Work in progress should be separate and the final content can be published blog-style with RSS updates.

An open license license is preferred, or at least free-to-use.

Answer (score 2):

The [SPIP](http://www.spip.net/rubrique25.html) content management system can do what you want, and it's free in al senses.

It has some extra interesting features for collaborative editing: a general private editors forum, private and public forums for each article/page, calendar and an internal messaging system. It's extendible with dozens of plugins and can be easily installed by anyone with a PHP/MYSQL shared hosting account.

The main website and free templates have a "classic" design, but the CMS, born in 2001, continues to be developed and has a large (mostly French) user community. The templating system is very flexible, once you learn how to work with it.

Comment: Where do I download this? Their website is somewhat confiusing.

Comment: There's a huge button in the top right corner of the link I've posted that links to: http://www.spip.net/en_download